# The primitive type int of FC_COLS does not have a field inBlockSize

Tags: java, eclipse

I am getting this error on the `lastStartCol = FC_COLS – inBlockSize;` and a similar error with `lastStartCol = ECONOMY_COLS – inBlockSize;`. Also not to sure what my teacher wants me to do with the for statement.Simple answers appreciated.

//Determine lastStartCol, the last legal start column for the given block //size in the row.

```
if(inRow < FC_ROWS)
    lastStartCol = FC_COLS – inBlockSize;
else
    lastStartCol = ECONOMY_COLS – inBlockSize;


for(int startCol = 0; startCol <= lastStartCol; startCol++)
{
    ...
```

Whole Class:

```
public class Airplane 
{
private Seat [ ] [ ] seats;
public static final int FIRST_CLASS = 1;
public static final int ECONOMY = 2;
private static final int FC_ROWS = 5;
private static final int FC_COLS = 4;
private static final int ECONOMY_ROWS = 5;
private static final int ECONOMY_COLS = 6;

public Airplane() 
{
    seats  = new Seat[FC_ROWS][FC_COLS]; 
    for (int i=0; i<FC_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<FC_COLS; j++) 
        {
            seats[i][j] = new Seat(Seat.WINDOW);
        }
        seats  = new Seat[ECONOMY_ROWS][ECONOMY_COLS]; 
        for (int x=0; x<ECONOMY_ROWS; x++) {
            for (int y=0; y<ECONOMY_COLS; y++) 
            {
                seats[x][y] = new Seat(Seat.WINDOW);
            }
        }
    }
}
public String toString()
{
    String str = "";
    for (int i=0; i<FC_ROWS; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<FC_COLS; j++) 
        {
            str= str + seats[i][j].toString();
        }
        str = str + "\n";
    }
    return str;
}   

public String toString2()
{
    String z = "";
    for (int x=0; x<ECONOMY_ROWS; x++) {
        for (int y=0; y<ECONOMY_COLS; y++) 
        {
            z= z + seats[x][y].toString();
        }
        z = z + "\n";
    }
    return z;
}
private int findEmptyBlockInRow(int inRow, int inBlockSize, int inSeatType)
{
    int lastStartCol;

    //Determine lastStartCol, the last legal start column for the given block //size in the row.
    if(inRow < FC_ROWS)
        lastStartCol = FC_COLS – inBlockSize;
    else
        lastStartCol = ECONOMY_COLS – inBlockSize;


    for(int startCol = 0; startCol <= lastStartCol; startCol++)
    {
        ...

        //Starting at startCol, check for inBlockSize consecutive seats //that are empty and include the seat type you are looking for. If //a seat block is found, return the startCol. 

        for(int i = 0; i < inBlockSize; i++)
        {
            if (seats[inRow][startCol + i].isAvailable()==true)  
            {
                int f = 0;
                f++;
            }


            if (seats[inRow][startCol + i].getSeatType() == inSeatType)
            {
                int d = inSeatType;
            }

            return lastStartCol;
        }

    }
}
 }
```

Comment: post the Exception what you are getting.

Comment: the error is in the title unless your talking about something else.
this is the exception but its because i haven't finished the method yet.
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems: 
 The method findEmptyBlockInRow(int, int, int) from the type Airplane is not visible
 The method findEmptyBlockInRow(int, int, int) from the type Airplane is not visible
 The method findEmptyBlockInRow(int, int, int) from the type Airplane is not visible
 The method findEmptyBlockInRow(int, int, int) from the type Airplane is not visible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is something mistake by typing.

Try this like in this line `lastStartCol = FC_COLS - inBlockSize;` first remove this `-` and again enter the minus symbol from keyboard.

do the above from this line also `lastStartCol = ECONOMY_COLS - inBlockSize;`

OR

Try to replace your line of code with below.

```
if(inRow < FC_ROWS)
    lastStartCol = FC_COLS - inBlockSize;
else
    lastStartCol = ECONOMY_COLS - inBlockSize;
```